# python scripts showing different result( with one error ) in two similar input files

Tags: python

The script, originally taken and modified from (http://globplot.embl.de/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Copyright (C) 2003 Rune Linding - EMBL
# GlobPlot TM
# GlobPlot is licensed under the Academic Free license

from string import *
from sys import argv
from Bio import File
from Bio import SeqIO
import fpformat
import sys
import tempfile
import os
from os import system,popen3
import math

# Russell/Linding
RL =     {'N':0.229885057471264,'P':0.552316012226663,'Q':-0.187676577424997,'A':-0.261538461538462,'R':-0.176592654077609, \
  'S':0.142883029808825,'C':-0.0151515151515152,'T':0.00887797506611258,'D':0.227629796839729,'E':-0.204684629516228, \
  'V':-0.386174834235195,'F':-0.225572305974316,'W':-0.243375458622095,'G':0.433225711769886,'H':-0.00121743364986608, \
  'Y':-0.20750516775322,'I':-0.422234699606962,'K':-0.100092289621613,'L':-0.337933495925287,'M':-0.225903614457831}

def Sum(seq,par_dict):
sum = 0
results = []
raws = []
sums = []
p = 1
for residue in seq:
    try:
        parameter = par_dict[residue]
    except:
        parameter = 0
    if p == 1:
        sum = parameter
    else:
        sum = sum + parameter#*math.log10(p)
    ssum = float(fpformat.fix(sum,10))
    sums.append(ssum)
    p +=1
return sums

def getSlices(dydx_data, DOM_join_frame, DOM_peak_frame, DIS_join_frame,     DIS_peak_frame):
DOMslices = []
DISslices = []
in_DOMslice = 0
in_DISslice = 0
beginDOMslice = 0
endDOMslice = 0
beginDISslice = 0
endDISslice = 0
for i in range( len(dydx_data) ):
#close dom slice
    if in_DOMslice and dydx_data[i] > 0:
        DOMslices.append([beginDOMslice, endDOMslice])
        in_DOMslice = 0
#close dis slice
    elif in_DISslice and dydx_data[i] < 0:
        DISslices.append([beginDISslice, endDISslice])
        in_DISslice = 0
    # elseif inSlice expandslice
    elif in_DOMslice:
        endDOMslice += 1
    elif in_DISslice:
        endDISslice += 1
# if not in slice and dydx !== 0 start slice
    if dydx_data[i] > 0 and not in_DISslice:
        beginDISslice = i
        endDISslice = i
        in_DISslice = 1
    elif dydx_data[i] < 0 and not in_DOMslice:
        beginDOMslice = i
        endDOMslice = i
        in_DOMslice = 1
#last slice
if in_DOMslice:
    DOMslices.append([beginDOMslice, endDOMslice])
if in_DISslice:
    DISslices.append([beginDISslice,endDISslice])
k = 0
l = 0
while k < len(DOMslices):
    if k+1 < len(DOMslices) and DOMslices[k+1][0]-DOMslices[k][1] < DOM_join_frame:
        DOMslices[k] = [ DOMslices[k][0], DOMslices[k+1][1] ]
        del DOMslices[k+1]
    elif DOMslices[k][1]-DOMslices[k][0]+1 < DOM_peak_frame:
        del DOMslices[k]
    else:
        k += 1
while l < len(DISslices):
    if l+1 < len(DISslices) and DISslices[l+1][0]-DISslices[l][1] < DIS_join_frame:
        DISslices[l] = [ DISslices[l][0], DISslices[l+1][1] ]
        del DISslices[l+1]
    elif DISslices[l][1]-DISslices[l][0]+1 < DIS_peak_frame:
        del DISslices[l]
    else:
        l += 1
return DOMslices, DISslices


def SavitzkyGolay(window,derivative,datalist):
SG_bin = 'sav_gol'
stdin, stdout, stderr = popen3(SG_bin + '-D' + str(derivative) + ' -n' + str(window)+','+str(window))
for data in datalist:
    stdin.write(`data`+'\n')
try:
    stdin.close()
except:
    print stderr.readlines()
results = stdout.readlines()
stdout.close()
SG_results = []
for result in results:
    SG_results.append(float(fpformat.fix(result,6)))
return SG_results


def reportSlicesTXT(slices, sequence, maskFlag):
if maskFlag == 'DOM':
    coordstr = '|GlobDoms:'
elif maskFlag == 'DIS':
    coordstr = '|Disorder:'
else:
    raise SystemExit
if slices == []:
    #by default the sequence is in uppercase which is our search space
    s = sequence
else:
    # insert seq before first slide
    if slices[0][0] > 0:
        s = sequence[0:slices[0][0]]
    else:
        s = ''
    for i in range(len(slices)):
        #skip first slice
        if i > 0:
            coordstr = coordstr + ', '
        coordstr = coordstr + str(slices[i][0]+1) + '-' + str(slices[i][1]+1)
        #insert the actual slice
        if maskFlag == 'DOM':
            s = s + lower(sequence[slices[i][0]:(slices[i][1]+1)])
            if i < len(slices)-1:
                s = s + upper(sequence[(slices[i][1]+1):(slices[i+1][0])])
            #last slice
            elif slices[i][1] < len(sequence)-1:
                s = s + lower(sequence[(slices[i][1]+1):(len(sequence))])
        elif maskFlag == 'DIS':
            s = s + upper(sequence[slices[i][0]:(slices[i][1]+1)])
            #insert untouched seq between disorder segments, 2-run labelling
            if i < len(slices)-1:
                s = s + sequence[(slices[i][1]+1):(slices[i+1][0])]
            #last slice
            elif slices[i][1] < len(sequence)-1:
                s = s + sequence[(slices[i][1]+1):(len(sequence))]
return s,coordstr


def runGlobPlot():
try:
    smoothFrame = int(sys.argv[1])
    DOM_joinFrame = int(sys.argv[2])
    DOM_peakFrame = int(sys.argv[3])
    DIS_joinFrame = int(sys.argv[4])
    DIS_peakFrame = int(sys.argv[5])
    file = str(sys.argv[6])
    db = open(file,'r')
except:
    print 'Usage:'
    print '         ./GlobPipe.py SmoothFrame DOMjoinFrame DOMpeakFrame DISjoinFrame DISpeakFrame FASTAfile'
    print '         Optimised for ELM: ./GlobPlot.py 10 8 75 8 8 sequence_file'
    print '         Webserver settings: ./GlobPlot.py 10 15 74 4 5 sequence_file'
    raise SystemExit
for cur_record in SeqIO.parse(db, "fasta"):
    #uppercase is searchspace
    seq = upper(str(cur_record.seq))
    # sum function
    sum_vector = Sum(seq,RL)
    # Run Savitzky-Golay
    smooth = SavitzkyGolay('smoothFrame',0, sum_vector)
    dydx_vector = SavitzkyGolay('smoothFrame',1, sum_vector)
    #test
    sumHEAD = sum_vector[:smoothFrame]
    sumTAIL = sum_vector[len(sum_vector)-smoothFrame:]
    newHEAD = []
    newTAIL = []
    for i in range(len(sumHEAD)):
        try:
            dHEAD = (sumHEAD[i+1]-sumHEAD[i])/2
        except:
            dHEAD = (sumHEAD[i]-sumHEAD[i-1])/2
        try:
            dTAIL = (sumTAIL[i+1]-sumTAIL[i])/2
        except:
            dTAIL = (sumTAIL[i]-sumTAIL[i-1])/2
        newHEAD.append(dHEAD)
        newTAIL.append(dTAIL)
    dydx_vector[:smoothFrame] = newHEAD
    dydx_vector[len(dydx_vector)-smoothFrame:] = newTAIL
    globdoms, globdis = getSlices(dydx_vector, DOM_joinFrame, DOM_peakFrame, DIS_joinFrame, DIS_peakFrame)
    s_domMask, coordstrDOM = reportSlicesTXT(globdoms, seq, 'DOM')
    s_final, coordstrDIS = reportSlicesTXT(globdis, s_domMask, 'DIS')
    sys.stdout.write('>'+cur_record.id+coordstrDOM+coordstrDIS+'\n')
    print s_final
    print '\n'
return

runGlobPlot()
```

My input and output files are here: [link](https://sites.google.com/site/iicbbioinformatics/share)

This script takes a input (input1.fa)  and gives following output output1.txt

But when I try to run this script with similar type but larger input file (input2.fa)  .. It shows following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final_script_globpipe.py", line 207, in <module>
    runGlobPlot()
  File "final_script_globpipe.py", line 179, in runGlobPlot
    smooth = SavitzkyGolay('smoothFrame',0, sum_vector)
  File "final_script_globpipe.py", line 105, in SavitzkyGolay
    stdin.write(`data`+'\n')
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I have no idea where the problem is. Any type of suggestion is appriciated.

I am using python 2.7 in windows 7 machine. I have also attached the Savitzky Golay module  which is needed to run the script.

Thanks

Comment: Hi J Carter, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried investigating the lines of code identified in the error callstack, to see if there are any clues there? It must be possible to find out _something_ about the error conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vince Bowdren, I have tried but have no idea what the error is about. It seems that it got some problem in Savitzky Golay module of code, but it is unlikely  as this code gives successful output with my smaller input file

Comment: Can you add `print(repr(data))` immediately before the line with the error (`stdin.write(\`data\`+'\n')`), and post the output please?  +Edit: I expect there's a lot of it, which is probably where the problem is.

Comment: -0.2259036145
-0.4024962685
-0.8247309681
-1.0124075456
-1.2170921751
-1.2322436902
-1.4199202677
-1.5200125573
-1.2901274998
-1.6280609957
-1.8157375732
-2.0772760347
-2.2538686888
Traceback (most recent call last):

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
After trying to reproduce the error on linux it's showing a similar behavior, working fine with the first file but with the second is returning Errno32.
Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Glob.py", line 207, in <module>
    runGlobPlot()
  File "Glob.py", line 179, in runGlobPlot
    smooth = SavitzkyGolay('smoothFrame',0, sum_vector)
  File "Glob.py", line 105, in SavitzkyGolay
    stdin.write(`data`+'\n')
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Update:

Some calls of the **SG_bin** return that the **-n parameter** is the wrong  type.

```
Wrong type of parameter for flag -n. Has to be unsigned,unsigned
```

This parameter comes from the **window** variable that is passed to the **SavitzkyGolay** function.

Surrounding the stdin.write with a trycatch block reveals that it breaks a hadnfull of times.

```
try:
   for data in datalist:
        stdin.write(repr(data)+'\n')
except:
    print "It broke"
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, you are right, it is a encoding issue, but after  changing them with quotes I still got the same error

Comment: Then it might be that it just has some wrong input data, do you have any other input file to test with?

Comment: yes, I have tested with 3 more input files, it gives similar error

Comment: On the [download page](http://globplot.embl.de/html/download.html) they state that you need to use BioPython (never heard of it before to be honest) are you using it or you are just using plain python?

Comment: @J.Carter Any progress?

Comment: no sir. & biopython is nothing but some pre-written  python modules for biological data analysis. I already have it in my system.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce your environment and check where it breaks.

Comment: @J.Carter what parameters are you passing? The  default ones?

Comment: `\`data\`` is an obsolete way of saying `repr(data)`.

Comment: Check the length of `repr(data)` when it fails... I suspect you're trying to shove too much data down the pipe at once.

Comment: @RoadieRich It oscillates between 13 and 16 char.

Comment: Hahaha, oh well, i'm kinda starting to run out of ideas, as the **window** that is passed is hardcoded. My last thing to check it would be to split the data and check what is different on the ones that blow up, but since I don't even have a remote idea about how this data is stored or what it even means it's quite a difficult task for me :)

Comment: may be I am wrong, but when I move my sav_gol executible to different directory, it gives the first output (only)..

Comment: If you move the sav_gol it should't even be able to run properly, i don't get what you're trying to say.

Comment: I just change the "SG_bin =" destination, anyway, it only just gives the first output.. nothing productive

Comment: Hi @J.Carter I'm trying to compare the two files (yours and the original one) seeking for what changes you made that could break it, but copy pasting the code from stackoverflow outputs a weird indented ball of code that is not helping me in any way. Could you please give some insight in **what changes you made** to the original code?